# Issue with using os.system to call another script

Tags: python, printing, os.system

I am working on another issue which requires me to use os.system() to call another python script. I know that subprocess is the better solution but for what I'm trying to do but I can't use that and am stuck with os.system(). I set up a small test program as follows to try and figure out os.system():

sript1.py

```
import os
import sys

os.system("C:/Users/user/Documents/code/test/called_script.py")
```

called_script.py

```
import os
import sys

sourceFile = open('C:/Users/user/Documents/code/test/test.txt', 'w')
print("hi", file = sourceFile)
sourceFile.close()
```

If I run script1.py it will not create (or if it already exists write to) test.txt

But if I run called_script.py directly it will create/write to the file test.txt

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but could someone help me out with why running script1.py is not getting me the desired outcome?

Comment: How do you run `called_script.py` directly? Through command line? By clicking on it?

Comment: What about "python C:/Users/user/Documents/code/test/called_script.py"?  Generally a .py file isn't directly executable from the Windows command line.  Also, you might need to use \ instead of / in the path.

Comment: I'm running it inside of VS Code. Thanks, adding "py C:/Users/user/Documents/code/test/called_script.py" worked. Now, if I was to deploy this project as an .exe file to an environment where Python was not installed, do I have to compile both as .exe files and use "C:/Users/user/Documents/code/test/called_script.exe"?

Comment: @user2334659 Yes, you have to compile both files (pyinstaller works great for that, just use the --onefile argument) and you have ti change the Comand to the one you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the above comments, the solution is that script1.py should read

```
os.system("py C:/Users/user/Documents/code/test/called_script.py")
```

Because Windows does not know what to do with a .py file otherwise.